# Profile References Search

Tags: user-profile

I would like to consolidate a great amount of profiles which are unnecessary. But I would like to see all of the places in which those profiles are referenced in order to prevent any problems. This would include such references as Sharing Rules ; Report Folders ; Page Layout Assignments etc.

Does anybody know how any tools which could provide for this ?

btw - I'm using PermComparator for other types of comparison as well.

Answer (score 0):

Our Snapshot tool on the AppExchange will generate many reports on Profiles and Permission Sets. You can generate a Relationship Matrix between Profiles and any other Metadata Type. You can search for a Profile by name and see every Metadata Type that references it. There is a Similar Assets report which will show Profiles that are similar. You can assign users to a Profile or Permission Set, and delete the actual Profile or Permission Set when finished. Hope that helps, full disclosure, I am the CTO of Metazoa and we publish the Snapshot Tool.